# Why can't I catch std::filesystem::filesystem_error?

Tags: c++, exception, c++17

I rarely use exceptions in C++, and my knowledge is very rusty on them. I use [`recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) and noticed that exceptions are thrown if the passed path does not exist.

```cpp
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

try {
  for (auto it = fs::recursive_directory_iterator("abc"); it != fs::recursive_directory_iterator(); ++it ) {
    /// 
  }
} catch(fs::filesystem_error& exc) {
  error = exc.code().message();
}
```

On executing the code, I still receive this fatal error:

> libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::__fs::filesystem::filesystem_error: filesystem error: in recursive_directory_iterator: No such file or directory ["abc"]

I suspected the constness of the exception, but most example use a no-const ref for the exception.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the thrown exception has nothing to do, whatsoever, with the shown code. The shown code attempting to iterate over "abc", and the exception references something else entirely. In any case, any debugger worth its salt can trap an exception, and a backtrace will easily identify whether or not it originated from a try/catch scope. Please show the backtrace from your debugger (and point out where exactly the try/catch scope is logged)?

Comment: Please show a [mre] to ensure that the problematic code isn't any of the code that you have chosen not to show us.  Your error describes a problem with directory `"sfdasf"`, which is nowhere in the code you are showing here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Great observation, I have to admit though I modified the path as `sfdasf` was in the original code snippet. I will attempt to make a MVCE

Comment: Exceptions *should* be caught using a const ref: `catch(const std::filesystem::filesystem_error& exc)`

Comment: I also tried a const-ref, with no success. I get the feeling that `fs::filesystem_error` isn't the same as `std::__1::__fs::filesystem::filesystem_error` since the generic `catch (...)` catches the exception. I updated the question and added the namespace definition.

Comment: Note that your edit is still not a [mre].  Your code [will not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/7xxWMen37).

Comment: Confirmed, I used an online compiler and can't reproduce it there, the exception is caught as expected. As mentioned, I suspect a mismatch in the types that I use in `catch` and the one that is actually thrown.

Comment: @HelloWorld sounds like a bug in your compiler's implementation of the `filesystem` namespace. You can catch `std::exception` instead (or any other standard exception that `filesystem_error` derives from) and see what is actually caught.